# docker build --tag= not setting tag, repository correctly

Tags: docker

I am following the official [docker get started guide](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/). Instead of using a python image, I would like to setup a mongodb instance. I decided on a tag, and found the relevant [Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/blob/89f19dc16431025c00a4709e0da6d751cf94830f/4.0/Dockerfile). I have the docker file inside a otherwise empty folder (the content is the same as in the link).

I ran `docker build --tag=mongoplayground:1.0.0 .`, and then `docker image ls`, but the output I get is this:

```
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
<none>              <none>              838852e4e564        32 minutes ago      409MB
ubuntu              xenial              9361ce633ff1        2 weeks ago         118MB
```

I would expect the repository name to be `mognoplayground` and the tag to be `1.0.0`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does docker build outputs to the console?

Comment: ugh. it seems that the build is not executing correctly - it stops at step 19/22...```Removing intermediate container e9d443877f6a
 ---> 838852e4e564
Step 19/22 : COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder548546047/docker-entrypoint.sh: no such file or directory```

Comment: thats why I asked. try fixing the build issues first, the tag should be fine later

Comment: Thanks, I was only using a single file from the repo instead of the whole image repo, this is why the build was failing. Voted to close the question since the problem was not with `docker build --tag`

Comment: My pleasure :))

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
 docker build -t mongoplayground:1.0.0 .
```

Answer (score 1):

Should be either:

```
docker build --tag mongoplayground:1.0.0 .
```

or:

```
docker build -t mongoplayground:1.0.0 .
```